# Evaluating a t-test on regression coefficients using statsmodels

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have a dataset with about 100+ features. I also have a small set of covariates.

I build an OLS linear model using statsmodels for y = x + C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + ... + Cn for each covariate, and a feature x, and a dependent variable y.

I'm trying to perform hypothesis testing on the regression coefficients to test if the coefficients are equal to 0. I figured a t-test would be the appropriate approach to this, but I'm not quite sure how to go about implementing this in Python, using statsmodels.

I know, particularly, that I'd want to use http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.t_test.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.t_test

But I am not certain I understand the r_matrix parameter. What could I provide to this? I did look at the examples but it is unclear to me.

Furthermore, I am not interested in doing the t-tests on the covariates themselves, but just the regression co-eff of x.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS`? This will perform a OLS regression, making available the parameter estimates and the corresponding p-values (and many other things).

```
from statsmodels.regression import linear_model
from statsmodels.api import add_constant

Y = [1,2,3,5,6,7,9]
X = add_constant(range(len(Y)))

model = linear_model.OLS(Y, X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.params) # [ 0.75        1.32142857]
print(results.pvalues) # [  2.00489220e-02   4.16826428e-06]
```

These p-values are from the t-tests of each fit parameter being equal to 0.

It seems like `RegressionResults.t_test` would be useful for less conventional hypotheses.

Comment: Shouldn't the results from the t-test be the same as if I had done that?

Comment: @TimelordViktorious They should, yes

Comment: That is, of course, assuming the hypothesis is the same, I imagine.

Comment: @TimelordViktorious Yes, assuming that the alternate hypotheses are of the form B_i<>0

Comment: I usually do something like this`tt = results.t_test(np.eye(len(results.params); print(tt.summary())` to check equivalence of t_test and the corresponding attributes like tvalues and pvalues.

Comment: What would be an example of a less conventional hypotheses?

Comment: @bmc anything one-sided or nonzero, or comparing an algebraic expression of the slopes to a value

Comment: Thanks Jared. Also, if we want to see a confidence interval for each parameter and its closeness to the population the data was sampled from, is that built in as well?